# Where can I find a list of all functions in the MinGW C libraries?

Tags: c++, c, mingw

I've searched the internet for some reference material containing a list of all C/C++ functions in the libraries that come with MinGW, but I only found large websites with hundreds of pages each one describing in depth every function. But I just want a plain list of all functions with their names and the required parameter types/names, and the header where each one of them can be found, without all the details (because I already know what they do, I just want to have a quick reference list that I could print, especially because I can't seem to remember the parameter lists).

Comment: You don't have any intellisense showing you the parameters you need?

Comment: Well, sometimes I am coding in a plain-text editor like Notepad.

Comment: Many library functions are actually very cryptically named, so you can't really figure out what they do by just looking at the name (for example, what the hell does [`strpbrk`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk) really do besides something to do with strings?). Instead I recommend that when you need to do something, you look for something that matches that, no matter the name. Or keep a link to a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) [site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) where you can see and list lots of standard functions.

Comment: In fact, usually I already know what most of the functions I call do. I just don't usually remember how many parameters there are or their types/order.

Comment: @FernandoAiresCastello, Experience and Intellisense :) Also, conventions and consistency. For example, with things like `strcpy`, the first is always the destination.

Comment: The problem is, I don't always have Intellisense available. Also, I am mostly used to other libraries, I don't have much experience with the C standard libary apart from some unforgettable functions like printf.

Comment: Well, if you've memorized all of those format specifiers, you've got the hardest one out of the way :p

Comment: @chris I only know %d, %i, %x, %f and %s :)

Comment: Well I'm still searching and can't find any list of C functions. Guess I'll have to just try all of them, and then I'll write my own C standard library reference paper :)

Comment: I don't know of a list, but you could extract the synopsis from the man pages.

Comment: On my Ubuntu machine, I get this list with `zcat /usr/share/man/man[23]/*.gz | grep '^\.BI' >functions.txt`. You must postprocess this list, but it's a start at least.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I can't do that because I'm on Windows, it's MinGW.

Comment: Yes I know, but MinGW is based on gcc. So it should have the man pages as well. Don't you have some sort of `c:\mingw\man\man3` directory or similar?

Comment: @OlafDietsche no, I have C:\MinGW_4_6_1\doc\manual, but there is absolutely nothing about the standard libraries in the manual.

Comment: Ok, then I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

1. http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/
2. http://www.cppreference.com/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Microsoft Visual Studio runtime reference](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=b8704100-0127-4d88-9b5d-896b9b388313&displaylang=en&tm) would address your concern?

Comment: I found an "alphabetical function reference" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/634ca0c2.aspx but it doesn't show the parameter lists, so it's useless to me. I couldn't find it anywhere so I'm just creating my own function list.